# How to make scons work properly

Tags: linux, scons

I'm trying to compile the [SndObj](http://sndobj.sourceforge.net/) library from the source.
Supposedly it's as easy as just running 'scons' from the top of the SndObj directory.
I get this:

```
nhnifong@ubuntu-nate:~/SndObj-2.6.6$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: The Options class is deprecated; use the Variables class instead.
File "/home/nhnifong/SndObj-2.6.6/SConstruct", line 58, in <module>

scons: warning: The BoolOption() function is deprecated; use the BoolVariable() function instead.
File "/home/nhnifong/SndObj-2.6.6/SConstruct", line 60, in <module>
SndObj Library version is 2.6.5
Building the Sound Object Library
scons tools in this system:  ['default', 'gnulink', 'gcc', 'g++', 'gfortran', 'gas', 'ar', 'filesystem', 'dvipdf', 'gs', 'jar', 'javac', 'javah', 'm4', 'rmic', 'rpcgen', 'swig', 'tar', 'zip']
Checking for Realtime IO support...
OS is Linux...
Checking for C header file alsa/asoundlib.h... (cached) no
Checking for C header file soundcard.h... (cached) no
Checking for C header file jack/jack.h... (cached) no
No alsa or OSS RT support
Host is little endian
swig exists...
Checking for C header file Python.h... (cached) no
Checking for C header file /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h... (cached) yes
Python version is 2.6
Checking for C header file m_pd.h... (cached) no
Checking for C header file ladspa.h... (cached) no

installing python module in /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
chmod a-x include/SndObj/*.h
scons: done building targets.
```

The first problem is that the C header files it claims are missing are all there in /usr/include/

The second problem is that the Python module is not actually installed in /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have one or more `config.cache` files left over. Those should all be deleted and the installation restarted.